# How to learn a Graph using ML

Tags: graph, machine-learning

I am new to Machine learning. I want to use the ML way to learn a graph. Graph has nodes and connections. Programmatically I can calculate Tabular information about all the nodes and their input output connections like:

```
out(A)=C, out(B) = C, in(C) = A, in(C) = B.
```

Above table is for a Graph where two nodes A,B have connections to one node C.
Time to time nodes can be added or removed, mostly not.
Can anyone please tell me how can I learn such Graph? Which ML methodology can I used, any simple going tutorial please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what learning do you want to do here? Do you want to just store the graph efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the more "traditional" machine learning systems wouldn't be able to do that -- what you want is statistical relational learning. Unfortunately this is a relatively new, complex and not particularly mature field.

Have a look at [Alchemy](http://ai.cs.washington.edu/projects/alchemy) though. It comes with quite extensive documentation that includes some examples. The examples should help you to get started. There's also a mailing list if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks, ok I wee Alchemy.